# Keycloak - NullPointerException in codeToToken on token retreive

Tags: nullpointerexception, openid-connect, keycloak

I'm trying to run keycloak as the simplest OpenID server with the simplest app to authenticate users.

My steps:

1. I run keycloak insance `docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak`
2. I log in into keycloak instance, create new client with id `swarm`, I set `Authorization Enabled` to true, I set Valid Redirect URIs to `http://myapp/test.php`, rest is default.
3. On `http://myapp/test.php` I have just link to `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=swarm&response_type=code&scope=code&redirect_url=http://myapp/test.php` which I click
4. I'm redirected to keycloak page, where I log in as admin/admin and I'm redirected back to `http://myapp/test.php?session_state=c15d4d10-31a9-41d8-a8ba-9ea84d8fd4fa&code=ey...FA` (I cut code, as it was long)
5. I'm trying to exchange that code for a token with `curl` manually, by calling `curl -d "client_id=swarm" -d "grant_type=authorization_code" -d "client_secret=51d9de29-35f8-4692-bdfc-72f4c0a5b25f" -d "session_state=62f12f56-968b-4068-bbb5-95e5c9f1bc23" -d "code=eey...FA" http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`
6. I'm getting 500 Server error with no message.

In Keycloak logs I'm getting `NullPointerException` when trying to get a token from openid with this logs:

> 10:02:16,987 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-14) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at > org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.codeToToken(TokenEndpoint.java:310)
>       at > org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.processGrantRequest(TokenEndpoint.java:172)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Not sure what I can do next. I'll be helpful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a `request_uri` in your request #5. Use the same as in the first request.